# How to go back to a checkpoint with Azure EventHub Trigger to Functions?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

I have an EventHub trigger implemented with Azure Functions App. My business logic implementation was wrong in that function and had to correct it. I have corrected my implementation on Functions App, how would I change the checkpoint to that Azure Function to go back 24 hours and make the stream data available to Functions App?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I needed to start processing of events in a Hub from scratch, I went to Blob Storage -> `azure-webjobs-hosts` container and deleted the blobs with names like `yournamespace.servicebus.windows.net/yourhub/$Default/X`. Those blobs store the current checkpoints, so if you restart the Function App, it will start processing from the first event.

I know it's hacky, but works for such basic scenario. Maybe somebody will suggest a better way.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me towards the checkpoint location. I see two files in the consumergroup folder. So far I have seen only one consumer I have registered to my function. Did my function might have registered two consumers for single function ?

Comment: Could not delete the file, it says file is leased. Even after breaking the lease it has the lease still and cannot delete those files under those consumer groups.

Comment: @Kannaiyan Event Hub has two partitions by default. Try stopping Function App and then deleting the files.

Comment: Thank you for the help and it worked. I could able to go to a different checkpoint as well. 1000 or 2000 back. Since, I know the estimated number I need to go back. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: @Kannaiyan, yes re-setting the sequence number should work but only if the sequence number has not wrapped around.  I just wanted to clarify that this approach may not work for all scenarios.

Comment: What is the recommended approach to go back with time on EventHubs?

Comment: @Kannaiyan, this is not supported right now but is tracked at https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/1240

Answer (score 2):

The problem remains that you likely don't know the sequence number used on each partition 24 hours ago, otherwise, Mikhail's suggestion may work with an modified step of going into each blob and editing the sequence number instead of deleting all blob entries.

You should probably just start from the beginning.  Here are the steps:

1. Go to the EventHub portal.
2. Create a new consumer group, e.g. name it "GroupB"
3. Edit your function.json and add the following entry to the trigger section,

"consumerGroup": "GroupB"

4. Save your changes.

You should see that your Function will start processing events from the very beginning on the GroupB consumer group.

Comment: Thanks Ling. Mikhail Answer seems to be the best approach without modifying the trigger to a different consumer group.