# Azure Function App and IoT Hub Event hub

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-eventhub, azure-iot-hub

I have a Azure Function App which is bound as a trigger to Azure IoT Hub Event Hub.

As soon as any event is received by IoT Hub it triggers the Function App function and the message is received inside the Function App.

I want to re-raise the triggers for old events and want them on Function App right from the beginning. How can I refire the IoT Hub events so that the Function App can receive them from the beginning?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to go back to a checkpoint with Azure EventHub Trigger to Functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46199269/how-to-go-back-to-a-checkpoint-with-azure-eventhub-trigger-to-functions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may create another consumer group for your EventHub and configure your Function's `function.json` to [listen to that consumer group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs).  This will allow your Function to read messages from the very beginning.